# getX value not changing if im not change the value from first textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I made question yesterday but is unclear.  [my unclear question :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045383/using-getx-inside-list-object-from-another-class-and-listen-the-value-changed)

I have made changes for my question here. I got some trouble getting the value from Rx object. When the first time page load, it does perfectly listen the value change, but when I add some category amount inside `DateClass`, the getX not working. But it working after I changing the first amount from textfield then the second textfield is listen the value change. Did I miss something?

here my code and I attach some screenshot below

1. First page, I adding the value then total is listening
2. then I add new category to insert new amount, the total not listening
3. I made change to first textfield value, total is listening
4. after I change the first value, total is listening to second textfield value

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  Function callback;
  MainClass({Key key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MainClassState createState() => MainClassState();
}

class MainClassState extends State<MainClass> {
  RxList<DateClass> dynamicPerDate = <DateClass>[].obs;

  GlobalKey<MainClassState> mKey = GlobalKey();

  String stringTotal = "";

  addPerDate() async {
    dynamicPerDate.add(DateClass());
    setState(() {});
  }

  calculate() {
    int total = 0;
    List<int> listAmount = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicPerDate.value.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; dynamicPerDate.value[i].listCategory.length > j; j++) {
        var a = dynamicPerDate[i].listCategory[j].amountCategory;
        print(a);

        if (a != null) {
          listAmount.add(a.value);
        }

        total = listAmount.sum;
      }
    }
    return total.toString();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    addPerDate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: mKey,
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: dynamicPerDate.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => dynamicPerDate.isNotEmpty
                    ? dynamicPerDate[index]
                    : Container()),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  addPerDate();
                  // calculate2();
                },
                child: Text('Add Date')),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Total All Amount From Category Class'),
            Obx(() => Text(calculate())),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DateClass extends StatefulWidget {
  RxList<CategoryClass> listCategory = <CategoryClass>[].obs;
  DateClass({Key key, this.listCategory}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DateClassState createState() => _DateClassState();
}

class _DateClassState extends State<DateClass> {
  addCategoryPerDate() {
    widget.listCategory.add(CategoryClass());
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    widget.listCategory = <CategoryClass>[].obs;
    addCategoryPerDate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Date', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
            ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: widget.listCategory.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => widget.listCategory.isNotEmpty
                    ? widget.listCategory[index]
                    : Container()),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  addCategoryPerDate();
                },
                child: Text('Add Category'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryClass extends StatefulWidget {
  RxInt amountCategory = 0.obs;
  TextEditingController amountController;
  CategoryClass({Key key, this.amountCategory}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoryClassState createState() => _CategoryClassState();
}

class _CategoryClassState extends State<CategoryClass> {
  MainClass mainClass = MainClass();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    widget.amountCategory = 0.obs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Amount'),
        TextFormField(
          controller: widget.amountController,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.amountCategory.value = int.parse(value);
              widget.amountCategory.obs;
              // MainClass().method();
            });
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: First page, I adding the value then total is listening]
[image: then I add new category to insert new amount, the total not listening]
[image: I made change to first textfield value, total is listening]
[image: after I change the first value, total is listening to second textfield value]

Comment: Make variable observable, wrap it with obx.

Comment: which variable should I obs? Cause in CategoryClass variable amountCategory is already obs. @NehilKoshiya